# PHP - Convert string to integer with thousand-seperator support

Tags: php, type-conversion

Either I googled wrong or I'm the first asking for this actually really simple functionality.

I have strings like "18.439", "500", "20.000" that need to be converted into integers: 18439, 500, 20000 (where I live, we use points as thousand seperators).

I was hoping for [intval()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.intval.php) to handle this, as in C# you can add a second parameter [NumberStyles.AllowThousands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/c09yxbyt(v=vs.110).aspx) which perfectly works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use str_replace in PHP . like this.

```
intval(str_replace('.','',$string))
```

Assuming you are dealing only with integers.

Comment: yeah well I guess I just forgot about that :D thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`str_replace` function](http://php.net/str_replace) for this:

```
$a = '18.439';
$a = (float) str_replace(['.', ','], ['', '.'], $a);
var_dump($a);
```

It will replace every `.` in your string to `''` (empty string) and every `,` to `.`, and then will convert the result to float.

If you need to result as `int` you can use:

```
$a = '18.439';
$a = (int) str_replace(['.', ','], ['', '.'], $a);
var_dump($a);
```